# how can I call a system call in freebsd?

Tags: freebsd

I created a syscall same as /usr/share/examples/kld/syscall/module/syscall.c with a little change in message.
I used kldload and module loaded. now I want to call the syscall.
what is this syscall number so I can call it?
or what is the way to call this syscall?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, if you check /usr/share/examples/kld/syscall directory you will see it contains a test program..... but hey, let's assume the program is not there.

Let's take a look at part of the module itself:

```
/*
 * The offset in sysent where the syscall is allocated.
 */
static int offset = NO_SYSCALL;

[..]
        case MOD_LOAD :
            printf("syscall loaded at %d\n", offset);
            break;
```

The module prints syscall number on load, so the job now is to learn how to call it... a 'freebsd call syscall' search on google...

Reveals: http://www.freebsd.cz/doc/en/books/developers-handbook/x86-system-calls.html (although arguably not something to use on amd64) and.. https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=syscall&sektion=2 - a manual page for a function which allows you to call arbitrary syscalls.

I strongly suggest you do some digging on your own. If you don't, there is absolutely no way you will be able to write any kernel code.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you take a look at Designing BSD rootkits, that's how I learned kernel programming on FreeBSD, there's even a section that talks all about making your own syscalls.